# Does poster.encode module supported in python appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Does `poster.encode` module supported in python appengine ??

if No , whats is the possible alternatives ?

Comment: What does it do, for those like me who are unfamiliar with it?

Comment: check this please http://atlee.ca/software/poster/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to deploy the module with your code by including it in your application's directory when deploying, but it does appear to be a pure python module and looking through the source I see no reason why it wouldn't work just fine in App Engine.

The only modules that won't work are those that use C extensions or make use of features like threads, sockets, etc. that are disabled in the App Engine runtime.  `poster.streaminghttp`, for example, almost certainly won't work, as it uses sockets.

Comment: how to deploy it with my code ? ,,please check this code http://atlee.ca/software/poster/index.html will be blocked by appengine or not ?!

Comment: @adham: just put the module in your application's directory along with your code and your app.yaml.  I don't think the example would work as it uses the streaming http handlers; if you just want to use the poster.encode module to encode things there should be no problem.

Comment: @Wooble thanks alot,, all what i want is to upload image (multipart/form-data encoding)  do you think i will need streaminghttp ?

Comment: Where are you trying to upload the image to, your app or from your app to somewhere else?  App Engine doesn't support streaming, but for image files as opposed to video or audio, I'm not sure why you'd want to stream them in the first place.

Comment: i want want to post image from my application to facebook , using graph URL with required parameters ? clear ? :)

Comment: i don't want to stream it , just i'm still researching to find a suitable way to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

from what I see in https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster/src/bd5ab4c5005c/poster/encode.py I doesn't see any class that would be forbidden by google app engine. Just upload it as any of your own code.